# Latin encoding issue

Tags: python, encoding, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am working on a python web scraper to extract data from [this webpage](http://www.azuolynas.klaipeda.lm.lt/tvark/tvark_2016-2017_2pusm/index.htm). It contains latin characters like ą, č, ę, ė, į, š, ų, ū, ž. I use BeautifulSoup to recognise the encoding:

```
def decode_html(html_string):
    converted = UnicodeDammit(html_string)
    print(converted.original_encoding)
    if not converted.unicode_markup:
        raise UnicodeDecodeError(
            "Failed to detect encoding, tried [%s]",
            ', '.join(converted.tried_encodings))
    return converted.unicode_markup
```

The encoding that it always seems to use is "windows-1252". However, this turns characters like ė into ë and ų into ø when printing to file or console. I use the lxml library to scrape the data. So I would think that it uses the wrong encoding, but what's odd is that if I use `lxml.html.open_in_browser(decoded_html)`, all the characters are back to normal. How do I print the characters to a file without all the mojibake?

This is what I am using for output:

```
def write(filename, obj):
with open(filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as output:
    json.dump(obj, output, cls=CustomEncoder, ensure_ascii=False)
return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the HTTP headers set on the specific webpage you tried to load:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=windows-1257
```

so Windows-1252 will result in invalid results. BeautifulSoup made a guess (based on statistical models), and guessed wrong. As you noticed, using 1252 instead leads to incorrect codepoints:

```
>>> 'ė'.encode('cp1257').decode('cp1252')
'ë'
>>> 'ų'.encode('cp1257').decode('cp1252')
'ø'
```

CP1252 is the fallback for the base characterset detection implementation in BeautifulSoup. You can improve the success-rate of BeautifulSoup's character-detection code by installing an external library; both [`chardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) and [`cchardet`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cchardet) are supported. These two libraries guess at MacCyrillic and ISO-8859-13, respectively (both wrong, but cchardet got pretty close, perhaps close enough).

In this specific case, you can make use of the HTTP headers instead. In requests, I generally use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.dammit import EncodingDetector

resp = requests.get(url)
http_encoding = resp.encoding if 'charset' in resp.headers.get('content-type', '').lower() else None
html_encoding = EncodingDetector.find_declared_encoding(resp.content, is_html=True)
encoding = html_encoding or http_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml', from_encoding=encoding)
```

The above only uses the encoding from the response if explicitly set by the server, and there was no HTML `<meta>` header. For `text/*` mime-types, HTTP specifies that the response should be considered as using Latin-1, which `requests` adheres too, but that default would be incorrect for most HTML data.

Comment: Doesn't this have a different potential problem in that it will always override the in-document specified encoding with the encoding provided in the charset header?

Comment: @pvg: yes, if the server explicitly sets an encoding *and* the HTML document sets one (via a meta header, say), then in this case the server content-type wins.  I'll update with a solution that looks for the HTML declaration first.